# Implementing Checkpointed interface: snapshotState() in flink is not being called

Tags: apache-flink

I have created a test below. I am testing snapshots. I supposed that snapshotState and restoreState should be called but it seems that it is not happening. Why?

The main code:

```
public class CheckpointedTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = 
                  StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        env.enableCheckpointing(5000);
        env.setParallelism(2);

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }

        DataStream<Integer> test = env.fromCollection(list);

        test.map(new CheckpointedFunction());

        env.execute();
    }
}
```

The function implementation is the following:

```
public class CheckpointedFunction implements MapFunction<Integer, Integer>, Checkpointed<Integer> {

    private Integer count = 0;

    @Override
    public Integer map(Integer value) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("count: " + count);
        Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random()*4000));
        return count++;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer snapshotState(long checkpointId, long checkpointTimestamp) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Snapshot count: " + count);
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Integer state) throws Exception {
        this.count = state;
        System.out.println("Restored count: " + count);
    }


}
```

Comment: the function is never checkpointed since the job finishes before the checkpoint interval has passed even once. You should try it with a source that continously creates new data.

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you!

Comment: I wonder would mapstate saved by the checkpoint? what if the program fail and stuff we saved are in mapstate?